# Xamarin Google Play Map Services Error 400 Bad Request

Tags: c#, android, google-play, xamarin

I've attempted to follow tutorials for both Xamarin (http://docs.xamarin.com/guides/android/platform_features/maps_and_location/maps/part_2_-_maps_api/), and Google Play (it is in the Google Play Services getting started page on Xamarin Studio) to get a working maps example.

Back in December, a friend of mine used my phone to develop a map app using his own laptop. However when I tried compiling his code on my computer, I was getting the same error below. I don't have another android phone to test with, but I can't figure out why it isn't working. I imagine the error lies within my target sdk, which is 19. The API key I'm using is provided from Google and pasted it in like the tutorials say, so I don't think that's the issue. So the issue must lay within the SDK I have, or my computer. I'm just not sure how to test it or further debug it.

The error being spit out over and over again until I leave the page is this:

```
[AndroidHttpClient$2] executeRequestSending() director.getClass()=class org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector [AndroidHttpClient$2] executeRequestSending()#finished <<<<< nafResponseWrapper=NafResponseWrapper [httpResponse=HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request, usedCipherSuiteAndroidName=TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_RC4_128_SHA] [AndroidHttpClient$2] execute() finalHttpResponse.getStatusLine()=HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request [AndroidHttpClient$2] execute()#finished
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out the package name was wrong when signing up for the API key. The hidden in the flood of messages about the 400 bad request.

Silly mistakes and such. I feel silly for making this post honestly.